# SQL - Extract values from key value pairs to array

Tags: sql, arrays, presto

I'm querying some **`data (SQL, presto)`**, the source data has an **array** **struct** that includes a `name` and `ID`. I need to have an **array**  of the `IDs`.

The data looks like:

```
[    { "id": 123456789,
     "name": "name 1"    },
    { "id": 234567891,
     "name": "name 2"    }
 ]
```

and I need it to look like:

```
[123456789, 234567891]
```

Do you know how I can achieve this?

Comment: It's: MAP_KEYS(MAP_FROM_ENTRIES(column))

Comment: If this solved your question, then you can post it as an answer. Answering your own question is totally ok on Stack Overflow, as it can be helpful to future readers.

Comment: @GMB thanks! posted as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's: `MAP_KEYS(MAP_FROM_ENTRIES(column))`